# How to format date to mm/dd/yyyy in moment / date-fns?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

Here I am receiving the last updated data as an API response like this

```
let data = {
          "year": 2021,
          "monthValue": 11,
          "dayOfMonth": 9
         }
```

I have to covert this above object into this format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Can convert the above data using string interpolation like this `${data.dayOfMonth}/${data.monthValue}/${data.year}` But is there any other way we can use libraries to get this work done.

For e.g in the above string interpolation method, can't able to add `0` at the beginning of the `dayOfMonth` and `monthValue` when they are given as single digits.

can we achieve this using `moment` or `date-fns`?

Comment: You can do this with moment. It has methods to set minutes, hours, days etc. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a library just to zero-[pad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) a 1–2 digit number:

```js
function pad2 (n) {
  return String(n).padStart(2, '0');
}

function format (data) {
  return `${pad2(data.monthValue)}/${pad2(data.dayOfMonth)}/${data.year}`;
}


const data = {
  "year": 2021,
  "monthValue": 11,
  "dayOfMonth": 9,
};

const result = format(data);
console.log(result); // 11/09/2021
```